# Macro to Print Named Range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to assemble a macro to bring up a dialog to choose your printer, then print a specific named range with specific properties. I started with a small test statement that works fine.

```
Sub test()
' test Macro

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "Print_20_Year"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

Then I moved into the bigger guns and I am not able to get it to work properly. I included the `MsgBox` in the macro to see if any of the items were triggering.

No errors, no `MsgBox` popup. Any thoughts?

*EDIT* This is my new and current code. It works fine, buuut as soon as I uncomment the printrowtiles, it breaks. This is code it gives directly from recording a macro.

```
Sub Print_20_Year()
'
' Print_20_Year Macro
'
'
'
'    Range("Print_20_Year").Select
    MsgBox "Step .4"
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
    MsgBox "Step .6"
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
   MsgBox "Step .7"
'    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
'        .PrintTitleRows = "$4:$13"
    MsgBox "Step .8"
'        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
'    End With
    MsgBox "Step .9"
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    MsgBox "Step 1"
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperTabloid
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    MsgBox "Step 2"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "Print_20_Year"
    MsgBox "Step 3"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much poking around, I realized that somehow the `printtitlerows` was interacting with a separate UDF I wrote seen below:

```
Function IsFormula(c)
IsFormula = c.HasFormula
End Function
```

This UDF was tied to a conditional format that highlighted cells which had formulas in it. We use this to easily recognize which information we had to change/enter manually. I can't explain why the UDF was creating the issue, but when I deleted it then my macro ran fine. After adding my formula macro again, I just added `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the beginning and end of the code. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get any MsgBox popups, then you don't even get past the first few lines. My suspicion is that something goes wrong right at the start:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "Print_20_Year"
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$4:$13"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""    <<<< this worries me. What are you trying to do?
    End With
    MsgBox "Step 1"     <<<<< if you don't get here, one of the lines before this causes a silent error...
```

I would recommend adding an `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` statement as the first line in your sub; then add (typically just before the end of the sub)

```
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Oops - an error occurred. " & Err.Description
```

this may take a bit more sleuthing on your part to solve...

Comment: I am not an expert in macros by any means. So I recorded a macro and went to editing it to make it dynamic. All the print settings, (including the `.PrintTitleColumns`) is untouched. I did read that `.PrintTitleRows` and `Columns` requires `Application.PrintCommunication = True`. I assumed that was the reason the macro handled it in this manner. The error handler is a good idea. I will give that a try tomorrow morning.

Comment: I added the error handler as you suggested, but there is no change. No error is thrown. I removed bits and pieces until I reached the point where the macro was working with every line except for `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$4:$13"`. Any idea why that would just essentially exit me out of the macro? I also have those rows within the print area. Could this cause the error?

Comment: You are saying that .PrintCommunication has to be = True for the .PrintTitleRows command to work. The fact that you have that line commented out, and that this is where the code fails, makes me suspect that's the problem. Is there an unhandled exception going on?...

Comment: It just exits the macro. I have tried turning PrintComms on and turning them off with no effect. I think there is a bug with the title rows and header/footers as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843484/macro-to-print-named-range

Comment: I updated my code. It just exits the macro as soon as I uncomment out the printtilerow lines. No error, no warning, its like the macro just finished, but without actually printing anything.

Comment: I tried running this exact code on another computer and it does not work. It also just seemingly exits the macro.

Comment: When you record a macro as you do the above steps manually, and then play that macro - do you get the same error?

Comment: If I record a macro and run it immediately afterwards, it does not work. It does the same thing where it just seemingly exits the macro. If I then comment out the `printrowtitles/columns` it will still error out. I have to manually go into `Page Layout>>Print Titles` and clear out the values. Then the recorded macro will run fine, but it won't obviously have the titles row printed on every page.

Comment: Stripping down the code again... not even this will run:

`Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show`
    `With ActiveSheet.PageSetup`
        `.PrintTitleRows = Range("Print_Header").Address`
        `.PrintTitleColumns = ""`
    `End With`
    `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("Print_20_Year").Address`
    `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False`

Comment: This works `Range("Print_20_Year").PrintOut`. As soon as I put the PrintTitleRows in there, it breaks. This `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = Range("Print_Header").Address` and this `Range("Print_20_Year").PrintOut` does not work.

Comment: I have tried literally everything I can think of including everything I could find on google. For example, I copy and pasted the code from this thread: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=144118. Still doesn't work though. I suspect it might be something with Excel 2010 as stated before. Can anyone confirm?